# How to prevent AWS Windows LightSail RDP from going to sleep?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, rdp

I have got an AWS Windows Server 2022 Lightsail instance with RDP access, and I require certain applications to run continuously on it. However, when I close the tab with the RDP or RDP client, the RDP enters sleep mode after 10 minutes, which disrupts my applications' functionality. I attempted to address this issue by modifying group policies, but I have yet to find a successful solution. Can you suggest alternative methods to prevent the RDP session from sleeping?

Tried editing group policies, changing the sleep times to never but that did not help me. Also tried simulating mouse clicks and similar, no luck